# Exception when using static dbcontext with entitydatasource with onContextCreating

Tags: entity-framework, webforms, dbcontext, objectcontext, entitydatasource

I want to share a single dbcontext across a session. I understand there are a number of issues with using shared, cached Dbcontexts.

So I create a global dbcontext and save it in a static class variable.

I am able create select, create new entities, do inserts and updates via the dbcontext in code behind calls without a problem

I want to use the same dbcontext in my entitydatasource controls within my webforms, for concurrency reasons. I do this by using the OnContextCreating and ONContextdisposing Events. This works fine for reading data but when I try and do an update via a entitydatasource (from a dataview, gridview etc) I get the following exception

```
    AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with 
another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique 
before calling AcceptChanges.
```

I have reduced the system producing the error to a ef5.0 datamodel, using a single table and a single  webform page with a single enitydatasource. I have reproduced the code below

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        static QuantumDataEntities dbcontext = null;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void OnContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dbcontext == null)
                    dbcontext = new QuantumDataEntities();

            e.Context = (dbcontext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        }

        protected void OnContextDisposing(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextDisposingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

As you can see it is very simple. Whenever the Entitydatasource needs an objectcontext to read,update etc, it calls OnContextCreating. I am creating the dbcontext on the first OnContextCreating call,  caching in a static class variable and reusing for future OnContextCreating calls. The OnContextCreating event is call a few times, first for page load, next for the post back when the edit button is pressed and finally (I think) for the actually dbsave.

If I get ride of the caching and just create a new dbcontext for each call it works fine. i.e
replace

```
 if (dbcontext == null)
    dbcontext = new QuantumDataEntities();

  e.Context = (dbcontext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
```

with

```
 dbcontext = new QuantumDataEntities();  
  e.Context = (dbcontext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
```

There is some other weirdness with this error. If I set up a OnUpdating event, that is supposed to get called before any updates are performed by the entitydataosource, it never gets called.
I have included the stack trace for the exception and the end of this text.

I would have like to test this with EF 6.0 Alpha 3, but the designers have moved the object context
into another assembly making it non compatible with entitydatasouce

This is a major roadblock to further development of our site. The only choice we have now is to move to a non shared dbcontext, which will cause a extreme performance issues (i.e loading the same 20K data set mutliple times on a page load - yes we can re-architect, we it will take weeks/months, which we dont have right now)

Questions ?

1. What is going on ?
2. Am I doing something wrong ? ( as opposed to poor architecture)

exception stack trace

```
[InvalidOperationException: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.]
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupKey(EntityEntry entry) +2518309
   System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.AcceptChanges() +159
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges() +356
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +376
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +87
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleUpdate(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation) +1091
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +425
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +89
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9642898
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Hi I have exactly the same problem but not been able to identify the problem...yet. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No,I have not fould a solution to the problem. I should check it in vS 2013 but we are going to move off entitydatasource to objectdatasource anyway as entitydatasource is not supported on EF 6